# PyCon 2012 Talk by David Mertz on Coroutines as Threads

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

In this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7R3-_ViNxk&t=1398) by David Mertz on Coroutines, Threads etc. from PyCon 2012, he shows an example of using coroutines(generators) as a replacement for threads:

Here is the slide content:

> A scheduler for weightless threads won't switch to a specific place,
>   but will round-robin or the like:

```py
def thread_scheduler(generators):
    thread_data = defaultdict(list)
    threads = [g() for g in generators()]
    while True:
        try:
            for t in threads:
                data = thread_data[t.__name__]
                consumer, data = t.send(data)
                thread_data[consumer].append(data)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

> Here consumer threads cannot be switched into directly, but once
>   reached will get injected data.

1) Is `generators()` a typo? Most likely `generator` is a list right? (I know you can write function that gives you some iterable that has generators in it; but for simplicity ...)

2) Why is the code catching only *one* `StopIeration` error when there are so many generators being looped?